# laravel 5.2 retrieve multiple records

Tags: laravel-5

i need help here in laravel i'm trying to get two records from the database and pass in these two objects so far the record is retreived but only one variable in passed to the views why is that?

```
$slides = \App\slides::all();
        $followup = Text_Pages::where('machine_name', 'Follow up')->firstOrFail();
        $branches = Text_Pages::where('machine_name', 'branches')->firstOrFail();

    return view('index', 
    ['slides' => $slides], 
    ['branches' => $branches],
    ['followup' => $followup]
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it like this

return view('index', ['slides' => $slides, 'branches' => $branches, 'followup' => $followup]);

Answer (score 0):

The view method expects all of the view's variables as its second parameter.

```
return view('index', [
    'slides' => $slides,
    'branches' => $branches,
    'followup' => $followup,
]);
```

Alternatively, you can use `compact` to create the array with a bit less typing:

```
return view('index', compact('slides', 'branches', 'followup'));
```